# Django Cant access auth User, Group object in custom data migration

Tags: django, django-migrations

My migration file looks like this:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations
from project.tools import do_nothing

def create_can_receive_group(apps, schema_editor):
    Group = apps.get_model("django.contrib.auth", 'Group')
    # Group operation added here

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('poreceiving', '0004_auto_20150616_0846'),
        ('django.contrib.auth', '0006_require_contenttypes_0002')
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(create_can_receive_group, do_nothing),
    ]
```

Here I want to access Group object of *django.contrib.auth*. 
I get the following exception.

```
*** LookupError: No installed app with label 'django.contrib.auth'.
```

I found somewhere that if we want to use other object which is not in app in which the migration is present then we should add latest migration of other app.

When I add *django.contrib.auth* latest migration to the dependency I get following :

```
django.db.migrations.graph.NodeNotFoundError: Migration poreceiving.0005_create_can_receive_group dependencies reference nonexistent parent node (u'django.contrib.auth', u'0006_require_contenttypes_0002')
```

Comment: Don't want to sound silly, but you have 'django.contrib.auth' in your INSTALLED_APPS ?

Comment: @PeterRosemann Yes I do have 'django.contrib.auth' in my INSTALLED_APPS.

Comment: Do you have a dependency on the auth migrations? See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/#accessing-models-from-other-apps

Comment: @DanielRoseman I added the dependency according to the doc but it says 'dependencies reference nonexistent parent node'

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this (look at the `migrations.swappable_dependency` part in the dependencies):

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.conf import settings
from django.db import migrations
from project.tools import do_nothing


def create_can_receive_group(apps, schema_editor):
    Group = apps.get_model("auth", "Group")
    # Group operation added here


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('poreceiving', '0004_auto_20150616_0846'),
        migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(create_can_receive_group, do_nothing),
    ]
```